# Go to the directory where the executable command lives

Tags: command

This is a command-line trick from a book-"The Productive Programmer":

```
pushd `which java`/..
```

The author says this command can temporarily go the directory where the executable command *java* lives.

When I typed this command in Linux, Bash complained that：

```
bash: pushd: /usr/bin/java/..: Not a directory
```

I also tried to change directory to `/usr/bin/java/..` directly:

```
$ pushd /usr/bin/java/.. 
bash: pushd: /usr/bin/java/..: Not a directory
```

Why did I fail? Why cannot change to a directory using `/..`? How to modify this command to fulfill the same task?

Comment: Java is a file in that directory. Try using dirname...

Comment: `path/..` depends on the path being a *directory* (where '..' is a reference to its parent).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That fails because `/usr/bin/java` is a file, not a directory.

You can do:

```
cd "$(dirname "$(which java)")"
```

Or use parameter expansion in `zsh`:

```
cd "${"$(which java)"%/*}"
```

Comment: A somewhat cleaner solution for ZSH would be `cd =java(:h)`